# Servletcontext attribute works inconsistently

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here, in this code, when I get the request, it will get the intakeNumber from the header and set it into the servletcontext. I am trying to get this attribute from the aspect class. This aspect will be executed after returning the response from the controller.

When I am getting the attribute from the servlet context, sometimes value is there and sometimes value is not there in the servletcontext. so setting attribute in servletcontext works inconsistently.

I have replaced it with servletRequest, and then I can get the intakeNumber all the time.

Though I used the servletRequest, I am not sure about how internally it is working.

1. Kindly provide knowledge about servletContext and servletRequest.
2. Please tell me when it should be used.
3. Please tell me why this issue is occurring.

Thank you!

```
@Component
public class APIAttributeInitializeFilter implements Filter{

@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,ServletResponse ServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain){


HttpServletRequest httpReq=(HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;
servletContext.setAttribute("intakeNumber",httpReq.getHeader("intakeNumber");
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use this to pass information to an aspect. Especially if that gets invoked afterwards, as things get cleaned up. If you want more knowledge about those classes read the Servlet Specification that explains exactly what those are.

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide more information. Can we use threads to store the data and get it in aspect classes?

Comment: Can I autowire HttpServletRequest in aspect class. Is this a good idea?

Comment: No it isn't (IMHO) as that ties your aspect to the web. Store the state in a thread local (like the SecurityContextHolder from Spring Security) and use that.